# How to put contents into table and then into separate TD's

Tags: jquery, html-table, match, word-wrap

This is to be done with jQuery:

**I've got the next exact HTML blocks massive (ordered only logically by ID):**

```
<!--html massive start-->
<span id="edtL1">myContent</span>

<input type="file" id="fln1" name="file1">

<span id="iCode1">somth</span>

<input type="checkbox" id="del_img1" name="del_img1" value="1">
<label for="del_img1">myDel</label> 
<!--/html massive end-->
```

**I need these blocks to be arranged within the table td's when page is loaded**. I've got a few of that blocks massives pregenerated by server with unique ID's each one on my page. I mean the following:

`edtL1, fln1, iCode1, del_img1` are unique ID/names. The next massive has +1 value (exmp. `adtL2` etc.)

So I need every table to be generated for every massive having those id's as much as they listed on page.

---

**When all is done** it must be like this:

```
<table id="codeTbl1"> <!--codeTd1, ..Td2 etc. are generated dynamically after page's loaded-->
<tr><td class="codeTd1">
<span id="edtL1">myContent</span>
</td></tr>

<tr><td class="codeTd2"> 
<input type="file" id="fln1" name="file1">
</td></tr>

<tr><td class="codeTd3"> 
    <span id="iCode1">somth</span>
</td></tr>

<tr><td class="codeTd4"> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="del_img1" name="del_img1" value="1">
    <label for="del_img1">myDel</label> 
</td></tr>
</table>
```

If there are more same massives with ID +1 met - they are generated to the next table but with `id="codeTbl2"`.

Hope I made myself clear. I need the simplest solution so I can modify it as I'm a novice to jQuery.

Comment: how to you like to have it .. on what event? or are you trying to execute for firebug console and can you mention the pattern

Comment: when you know elements ID in massive blocks, so you can regenerate them in jquery by reading them and creatting tables, can you get me the problem in this solution?

Comment: **experimentX**, the event is simple: when the page is loaded. I've specified the pattern in **When all is done** section. Dunno how to make it more clear. Mb you can forward me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is a "massive"?

You can use templates to build a table in jQuery:

http://encosia.com/2010/10/05/using-external-templates-with-jquery-templates/

http://encosia.com/2010/11/10/composition-with-jquery-templates-why-and-how/

http://encosia.com/2010/12/02/jquery-templates-composite-rendering-and-remote-loading/

Comment: No, I do not need to build a table. I need to wrap existing elements into the table dynamically.